# Site is reacting bizarre on a netbook (divs not completely displayed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I'm testing my website on a normal notebook, I have no problem with my website but when I'm testing this website on a Netbook (mini laptop) it has a strange behaviour.

You can see the website here:
http://www.benskesblog.com/projects/frontend/project/index.htm
(it works on IE9 and other modern browsers).

When I try it on my netbook the images aren't displayed completely. When I scroll I see another part of the images. Very strang. I've tested it on another netbook (and on other browsers) and I have the same problem. You can see it here:
http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/5168/titel1.jpg
http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/374/titel2k.jpg

Does someone now what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Different browser show things differently .... which browsers does it work in and which browsers does it not work in .... can you provide some code rather than a link ?

Comment: And did you know your website contains userids and passwords -> http://www.benskesblog.com/projects/frontend/project/article.htm?artid=5#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, IE9 isn't "modern" - it's "bleeding edge".

Also, your page doesn't work at all in IE6 - which is arguably the most common browser out there.

So you've really got two questions you need to ask:

1) What is the minimum browser I'll support (for example, IE9+FF7+Safari5 @1024x768 truecolor resolution)?

2) How will I degrade gracefully for users who don't support my minimum requirements?

Comment: I agree about IE9. :) Thanks for your feedback!
For this project HTML5 & CSS3 compatible browsers is enough (school project), but I don't understand this problem on a netbook.